# How to filter MultiValueField

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I need to filter SearchQuerySet by user, to show only objects, related to current user.

I have a model connected to another model by reverse FK:

```
class ItemList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
    list = models.ForeignKey(ItemList, related_name='items')
```

and here I have index for it:

```
class ItemListIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    users = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_users(self, obj):
        return [item.user.pk for item in obj.items.all()]
```

here's the ViewSet I use to make search requests:

```
class ItemListSearchViewSet(HaystackViewSet):
    index_models = [ItemList]
    serializer_class = ItemListHaystackSerializer
    filter_backends = [HaystackFilter]
    pagination_class = SmallResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self, index_models=[]):
        qs = super(ItemListSearchViewSet, self).get_queryset(index_models)
        qs = qs.filter(users__in=[self.request.user.pk])
        return qs
```

What I can't figure out, is why this `get_queryset` method doesn't work properly and I always get empty results for my searches.

Comment: Have you built your index? as in `./manage.py rebuild_index` and what if you change the `index_models` kwarg in `get_queryset` to `index_models=list()`

Comment: @CoryMadden, yeah, I've rebuilt index. Changing `[]` to `list()` obviously hasn't made any difference. When I comment out this `get_queryset` method, it returns search results, but it includes results for other users, not only for the current one, as it should.

Comment: Yea, I thought about the `list` thing after I commented and it didn't make sense, but I was already out. Can you put a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into the `get_queryset` after the `super()` call and mess with that and see if you can get the desired results out of it that way? Also, why are you using a MultiValueField?